# Псевдоклассы и прочее

Tags: html, css

Хотел бы поподробнее узнать про псевдоклассы и подобные. Можно ли как-то с помощью них выделять 2, 3, 4... т.д элементы? Ну, например, есть 4 diva с классом .example и мне нужно применить какие-либо стили к нему. Можно ли сделать так без создания дополнительных id и классов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child`:

```
.example:nth-child(1) {
  // стили
}

.example:nth-child(2) {
  // стили
}

.example:nth-child(3) {
  // стили
}

.example:nth-child(4) {
  // стили
}
```

**UPD.** Добавил пример:

```css
.example {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.example:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
.example:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}
.example:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
.example:nth-child(4) {
  color: purple;
}
p,
h1 {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  Див №1

  <p>Дочерний элемент со своим цветом</p>
</div>
<div class="example">
  Див №2
  <h1>Дочерний элемент со своим цветом</h1>
</div>
<div class="example">
  Див №3

  <h3>Дочерний элемент с наследованием</h3>
</div>
<div class="example">
  Див №4
  <h4>Дочерний элемент с наследованием</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Про это слышал... Но почему-то при верстке выделяются не те элементы, которые мне нужны. Выделяются дочерние элементы (например, в каждом из 4-х дивов есть какие-либо h1, p - они и выделяются).

Comment: @Андрей покажите свой код (css и html)

Comment: @MasterAlex, поправьте :nt**h**-child. @Андрей, всё зависит от разметки. Иногда `:nth-child`, иногда `:nth-of-type`, а иногда и к родительским элементам нужно применять псевдокласс, а не непосредственно к тем элементам, к которым собираетесь применять свойства CSS.

Comment: @Андрей, дочерние элементы наследуют некоторые стили родителя, если эти стили у них отсутствуют в css, добавил в ответ показательный пример.

Comment: @Deonis, да-да, исправил уже, когда пример делал :)

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо Вам! Слышал, но не знал, для чего нужен nth-of-type) Еще раз спасибо, все работает